# Why is there a Non-exhaustive pattern in this function?

Tags: haskell

In this Script,

```
permutations :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
permutations x y
            | x==x-(y-1)     = x
            | (x>0) && (y>0) = permutations (x-1) y * x
```

I wonder why there is Non-exhaustive patterns in the function permutations.

Please help me.

Thanks for your advance very much!

Comment: What happens when one of the 2 arguments is negative? What if both are negative?

Comment: Please note that `x == x - (y - 1)` is equivalent to `y == 1`.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified what is the logic to handle the case where one or both arguments are negative. Your function, however, will happily allow negative arguments to be passed to it, and that is why you get the error. To fix this, you can add a catch-all `otherwise` statement at the end with your required error handling logic, like so:

```
permutations :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
permutations x y
        | y == 1 || x == y = x
        | (x>0) && (y>0) = permutations (x-1) y * x
        | otherwise = error "invalid input"
```

Note that I added a condition to the first case - you shouldn't be able to calculate permutations where `x < y`, so the base case should be either `y = 1` or `x == y`.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/AGSB86590)

An alternative solution which does give the correct answer would be something like this:

```
import Data.List(foldl')

permutations :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
permutations x y = if any (<=0) [x,y] then 0 else foldl' (*) 1 [x+1-y..x]
```